# traefik vs nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, traefik

Hi  I am using kubernetes and now need to make a choice between traefik and nginx ingress controller for ingress expose. I have googled a lot, but seems no such big difference, especially nginx just announce support grpc now. Anyone can give a advice? Thanks very very much!

Comment: Not a concrete advice here but I did some research: https://hackernoon.com/reviewing-grpc-on-kubernetes-8a705b928abd

Answer (score 2):

Found this comment at [stackshare](https://stackshare.io/stackups/nginx-vs-traefik) by Howie Zhao
The reasons for choosing Traefik over Nginx are as follows:

- Traefik built-in Let’s Encrypt and supports automatic renewal
- Traefik automatically enables HTTP/2
- Prometheus can be supported through simple Traefik configuration
- cookiecutter django integrates Traefik's configuration by default

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR -> microservice on docker/kubernetes -> traefik

Nginx: It is a high-performance, free, and open-source web server that serves as an HTTP and reverse proxy server. It has been widely used and has recently announced support for gRPC. It has good community support and documentation.

Traefik: It is a modern HTTP reverse proxy and load balancer designed specifically for microservices deployments. It offers seamless integration with Kubernetes and aims to simplify the deployment of microservices. Traefik has gained popularity for its ease of use and dynamic configuration.

Ultimately, the choice between Traefik and Nginx Ingress Controller depends on your specific requirements and preferences. If you prioritize simplicity and native Kubernetes integration, Traefik might be a good fit.